# Simplifying style.triggers with mulitibinding in WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, multibinding, multidatatrigger

In reviewing some code I wrote years ago, I have come across this trigger in my WPF style section. As can be seen, I am calling the MultiBinding Converter 7 times with the exact same references to Checkin, Checkout, and NotSeen to produce 7 different colors. This hits me as being awfully redundant and space consuming. There must be a better way.

Is there a way of accomplishing this with a shorter style? Also, is their a way of avoiding the MultiBinding Converter altogether in a MVVM framework? Could an attached behavior be used in place of this?

TIA

```
    <Style.Triggers>
            <!-- if checkout is null, then check for waiting time from the checkin value. Setter action occurs for DataTrigger Value -->
            <DataTrigger Value="1" >
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WaitStatus}">
                        <Binding Path="CheckIn" />
                        <Binding Path="CheckOut" />
                        <Binding Path="NotSeen" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource VioletBrush}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="2" >
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WaitStatus}">
                        <Binding Path="CheckIn" />
                        <Binding Path="CheckOut" />
                        <Binding Path="NotSeen" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BlueBrush}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="3" >
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WaitStatus}">
                        <Binding Path="CheckIn" />
                        <Binding Path="CheckOut" />
                        <Binding Path="NotSeen" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TurquoiseBrush}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="4" >
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WaitStatus}">
                        <Binding Path="CheckIn" />
                        <Binding Path="CheckOut" />
                        <Binding Path="NotSeen" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource GreenBrush}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="5" >
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WaitStatus}">
                        <Binding Path="CheckIn" />
                        <Binding Path="CheckOut" />
                        <Binding Path="NotSeen" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource YellowBrush}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="6" >
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WaitStatus}">
                        <Binding Path="CheckIn" />
                        <Binding Path="CheckOut" />
                        <Binding Path="NotSeen" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource OrangeBrush}" />
            </DataTrigger>
            <DataTrigger Value="7" >
                <DataTrigger.Binding>
                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource WaitStatus}">
                        <Binding Path="CheckIn" />
                        <Binding Path="CheckOut" />
                        <Binding Path="NotSeen" />
                    </MultiBinding>
                </DataTrigger.Binding>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RedBrush}" />
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
```

Comment: why don't you return directly a brush instead of an int? multibind the background directly to your converter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First approach using Custom DataTrigger** 

Create custom DataTrigger class where you programically define its binding but in code you set Setter.

```
class DataTriggerBinding : DataTrigger
{
    public DataTriggerBinding()
    {
        SetBinding();
    }

    private void SetBinding()
    {
        var multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("CheckIn"));
        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("CheckOut"));
        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("NotSeen"));
        multiBinding.Converter = new WaitStatus();
        this.Binding = multiBinding;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
  <Label Content="{Binding Age}">
    <Label.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Label">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <local:DataTriggerBinding Value="1">
                    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
                </local:DataTriggerBinding>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Label.Style>
</Label>
```

**Latter approach using attached behavior**

```
class DataTriggerBinding : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsCustomBindingProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
        "CustomBinding", typeof(bool), typeof(DataTriggerBinding), new PropertyMetadata((x, y) =>
        {
            SetBinding((DataTrigger)x);
        }));

    public static void SetIsCustomBinding(DependencyObject element, bool value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsCustomBindingProperty, value);
    }

    public static bool GetIsCustomBinding(DependencyObject element)
    {
        return (bool)element.GetValue(IsCustomBindingProperty);
    }

    private static void SetBinding(DataTrigger dataTrigger)
    {
        var multiBinding = new MultiBinding();
        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("CheckIn"));
        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("CheckOut"));
        multiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("NotSeen"));
        multiBinding.Converter = new WaitStatus();
        dataTrigger.Binding = multiBinding;
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
    <DataTrigger local:DataTriggerBinding.IsCustomBinding="True" Value="1">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Red"/>
    </DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Thank you. This helps immensely. As an aside question, I have written an attached property that is in a datacontext different from the viewmodel. The property returns the Brush, directly. But I can't get the value in the setter. Something like: <Style x:Key="listViewItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="v:ListViewItemBehavior.MyValue" Value="{Binding testvalue}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=(v:ListViewItemBehavior).Background}" />
        </Style>The value keeps insisting on the DataContext of the ListViewItem?

Comment: @Maximun how do you use a different datacontext for the binding of the value in the style setter??? Thanks.

Comment: Post new question since in comment is hard to paste code.